# How to style a WPF grid inside a <window>?

Tags: wpf, grid, styling

I have a WPF application with a grid that loads up in a window.

How do I do the following
**(1)** Add Header Gradient style (vertical graidents of 2 colors) 
**(2)** alternating row style to this grid below ?
**(3)** Hover (mouse over row highlighting) rowstyle for each of the rows in the grid ?

```
<Window
    x:Class="DiagramDesigner.PadDetailsWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner.Controls"
    Title="Pad Details"
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
    Width="750"
    Height="650" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Window.Resources>




    </Window.Resources>
<ScrollViewer Name="DesignerScrollViewer" Background="Transparent" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="650" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,-27,0">
                <!--<StackPanel>-->
                    <toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="dgMain" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="650" RowHeight="20">
                        <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Pad Name" Binding="{Binding Path=PadStream}" Width="80" />
                            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Parent" Binding="{Binding Path=Parent}" Width="50"/>
                            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Width="50"/>
                            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Path=Code}" Width="50"/>
                            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Volume" Binding="{Binding Path=Volume}" Width="80"/>
                            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Mass Rate" Binding="{Binding Path=MassRate}" Width="80"/>
                            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Min Flow Rate" Binding="{Binding Path=MinFlowRate}" Width="80"/>
                            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Max Flow Rate" Binding="{Binding Path=MaxFlowRate}" Width="*" />
                        </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                    </toolkit:DataGrid>
                <!--</StackPanel>-->
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="OK" Click="OnOkClick" Width="70" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="0,3,0,0" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Please let me know how the above asked styling could be done for the grid.

Comment: Why don't you use the DataGrid that is built in WPF 4? it has all the features you want already.

Comment: Thanks for that response however, I was wondering how this grid above can be styled using XAML styling ?

Comment: Unless you're using .net 3.5, the `DataGrid` is built into .net 4.0, so you don't need to reference the toolkit anymore.

Comment: @Baboon this is the same `DataGrid`.  The one in .net 3.5 toolkit is the same one as in .net 4.0 it just no longer requires a toolkit reference.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx) for the row header style:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Custom:DataGridColumnHeader}"  >
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#88800080" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" /> 
    <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridHeaderBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="Transparent" />
    </Trigger>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
            <Condition Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderMouseOverBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderBorderBrush}" />
    </MultiTrigger>

    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
            <Condition Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderMouseOverBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderBorderBrush}" />
    </MultiTrigger>
    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderSortedBackgroundBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderSortedBackgroundBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418904/wpf-datagrid-mouseover-on-datagridrow) for the mouseover property:

```
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
         <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                       Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Background"
                           Value="Green" />
              </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: I had a few bugs appear while compiling using the style above. <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Custom:DataGridColumnHeader}" , it said Custom was undefined.... How do i get rid of that issue ?

Comment: I had tried changing Custom to toolkit, and then it gave me other errors like for the line <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderMouseOverBackgroundBrush}" />  ,Cannot find resource DataGridHeaderMouseOverBackgroundBrush

Comment: There is a working example of this code at the link I provided.  The line you're getting an error on says that it is expecting an item called "DataGridHeaderMouseOverBackgroundBrush" to be defined as a resource.  You can create your own brush or go find the one defined in working example I linked.  FYI the working example is found at the very bottom of the post.